# Are those uses of sum and product notations correct?

Tags: analysis

I wanted to use th eproduct and um notations to describe the following sequences. Are those correct?

$$
6+12+18+24=\sum_{i=1}^4 6i \\
x_{1}-x_{2}+x_{3}-x_{4}+...+x_{7}-x_{8} = \sum_{i=1}^8 (-1)^{i-1}x_{i} \\
2*3*4*9*8*27 = \prod_{i=1}^3 2^i3^i \\
1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+...+10x^9 = \sum_{i=1}^{10} ix^{i-1} \\
a_{1}+(1+2)(a_{1}a_{2})+(1+2+3)(a_{1}a_{2}a_{3})+...+(1+2+...+n)(a_{1}a_{2}...a_{n}) = \sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{k=1}^ik \prod_{j=1}^ia_{j})
$$

Comment: Looks ok to me.

Comment: Yes, but I have an objection on formula $3$. Do not use $*$ . Use $\cdot$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They are OK**.

However I would like to point out one thing. In Algebra we rarely use the multiplication symbol. For example you write $2\pi$ instead of $2\cdot \pi$. The second one seems rather ungly.

If necessary , like in equation $3$ use the $\cdot$ symbol instead of $*$ symbol. That symbol clearly does not denote multiplication (the normal one rather other multiplications). The ast symbol is commonly used in Linear Algebra for other purposes as well as in the convolution theorem of Fourier Analysis.

So a better way of dispaying equation $3$ would be:

$$2\cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 27 = \prod_{i=1}^3 2^i3^i$$

Comment: Regarding notation. Yes, the asterisk is only used in programming languages because the middle dot or multiplication cross are not in the ASCII character set (blame the fact that early computer scientists involved in making the standard apparently forgot that math exists). But in the context of numbers, even $\times$ is quite ok (can't be mixed with cross product). For instance, most journals prefer $3.14\times 10^5$ to $3.14\cdot 10^5$.